# Use a value more than once in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create some flags in HTML/JS, each one on a separate canvas. I would like to be able to change the height and width of all canvases at the same time, but at the moment I must change them individually, which is very time-consuming. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

CURRENT CODE:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="500" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="500" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

etc...

Comment: tried giving class and using jQuery to change the props ?

Comment: Isn't it possible simply using CSS ? :)

Comment: Do as deepansh said. Create a class for those canvas and do `$('.class').css('height, 200)`

Comment: Setting `width` and `height` for a canvas via (HTML) attributes, and specifying them via CSS, are two different things. The first influences how many pixels the canvas will have, whereas the second will _stretch_ the existing canvas to be displayed at the specified size.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css

**css**

```
.mycanvas
{
   width:500px;
   height:300px;
   border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
```

**html**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas2" class="mycanvas">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

**js**

```
//get all canvas by classname
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("mycanvas"); 

//cicle all canvas 
for(var i=0;i<canvas.length;i++){
    // set new values
    canvas[i].style.height = "150px";
    canvas[i].style.width= "250px";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't mention *changing* the height and width.

Comment: The height and width of a canvas is not set by css. if you do it like this, you'll stretch / compress the dimensions of the canvas element, not the context itself. To change the actual width / height of the canvas you have to use js.